# Pasar estructura de formulario html a json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

estoy intentado pasar una estructura de formulario de html a json y claro la idea es que el formulario html es dinámico ya que cada vez puede ser diferente y necesito un código que me pase a json los elementos del formulario y sus características de esta forma por ejemplo:

-De una etiqueta h2,p, label sacar el valor:

ej-> "label": "Casa", "h2":"casa"..

-De un input text que me saque el type, placeholder, maxlength, valor.

- Da un input number los mismo que el input text pero añadiendo el min, max
  .......

-De un checbox que me saque de esta estructura boostrap:

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 2</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox disabled">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" disabled>Option 3</label>
</div>
```

pues valor del label y del input el type...

Yo he intentado hacer esto por ejemplo de este formulario de prueba:

```
<form id="conv" name="formulario" action="#" method="#">

<label for="usr">dfdf</label>
<input type="text" size="20" maxlength="44" placeholder="de">         



<p>scsc</p>

<p>dd</p>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checko1" value="">dcd</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checko2" value="">cdcd</label>
</div>

</form>
```

el script:

```
$(".convertir").click(function () {




function serializeSchema(form) {
    return [].map.call(form.elements, function (el) {
        return {
            type: el.type,
            name: el.name,
            value: el.value,
            placeholder: el.placeholder,
            size: el.size,
            maxlength: el.maxlength,
            min: el.min,
            max: el.max,
            step: el.step
        };
    });
}
;

var form = document.querySelector('#conv');
schema = serializeSchema(form);

console.log(JSON.stringify(schema, null, 4));
```

pero me saca esto de una manera que no quiero

```
[
{
    "type": "text",
    "name": "input_text1",
    "value": "",
    "placeholder": "de",
    "size": 20,
    "min": "",
    "max": "",
    "step": ""
},
{
    "type": "checkbox",
    "name": "checko1",
    "value": "",
    "placeholder": "",
    "size": 20,
    "min": "",
    "max": "",
    "step": ""
},
{
    "type": "checkbox",
    "name": "checko2",
    "value": "",
    "placeholder": "",
    "size": 20,
    "min": "",
    "max": "",
    "step": ""
},
{
    "type": "submit",
    "name": "",
    "value": ""
}
]
```

por ejemplo los label, h2 no me lo saca....

Comment: no es maner extraña es que está hecho con boostrap el checkbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás haciendo un mal uso de [`HTMLFormElement.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements):

> The `HTMLFormElement.elements` property returns an `HTMLFormControlsCollection` (HTML 4 `HTMLCollection`) of **all the form controls** contained in the FORM element, with the exception of input elements which have a `type` attribute of `image`.

En castellano:

> La propiedad `HTMLFormElement.elements` devuelve un `HTMLFormControlsCollection` (HTML 4 `HTMLCollection`) de **todos los controles del formulario** contenidos en el elemento FORM, con la excepción de los elementos cuyo atributo `type` sea `image`.

Por lo que sólo se busca en elementos del formulario, no en otras etiquetas.

Una solución podría ser la siguiente:

```js
function filtro(clave, valor) {
    if (valor == '' || clave == null) {
        return undefined;
    } else {
        return valor;
    }
};

function serializeSchema(form) {
  return [].map.call(form.getElementsByTagName("*"), function (el) {
    switch(el.tagName) {
      case 'INPUT':
        return {
          tag: el.tagName,
          type: el.type,
          name: el.name,
          value: el.value,
          placeholder: el.placeholder,
          size: el.size,
          maxlength: el.maxlength,
          min: el.min,
          max: el.max,
          step: el.step
        };
      case 'DIV':
      case 'ARTICLE':
        /* Estas etiquetas las ignoramos */
        return undefined;
        break;
      default:
        /* Del resto de etiquetas sólo obtenemos su contenido de texto */
        return {
          tag: el.tagName,
          text: el.innerText
        };
    }
  }).filter(function (e) { return e !== undefined; });
};

var form = document.querySelector('#conv');
schema = serializeSchema(form);
console.log(JSON.stringify(schema, filtro, 2));
```

```html
<form id="conv" name="formulario" action="#" method="#">
  <label for="usr">dfdf</label>
  <input type="text" size="20" maxlength="44" placeholder="de">
  <p>scsc</p>
  <p>dd</p>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checko1" value="">dcd</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checko2" value="">cdcd</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

He usado `form.getElementsByTagName("*")` para obtener hijos, nietos y demás niveles de descendencia. Si usamos sólo `form.children` no obtendremos nada más que el primer nivel de descendencia.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta pero esto sigue sin sacarme el valor de los labels o h3 y a parte si dentro del form tengo otras etiquetas que no quiero que me saque como los div, br que hago??

Comment: y no me saca en lenguaje jsonn  mas bien objeto

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo completo en tu pregunta? ¿Qué valores quieres sacar de los label y de los h3? Es que en tu pregunta no están esas etiquetas y no pones qué datos quieres de ellas.

Comment: me estás ayudando oscar peró me falta que me soluciones que me saque el valor de los label y p como por ejemplo <label>hola</label> { "tag": "LABEL", value:"hola" },

Comment: y la otra question si se pueden suprimir que no me saque otros elementos como el div, article etiquetas que estan dentro del formulario que no quiero que me saque

Comment: claro oscar es que es un formulario dinámico y hay veces que me saca <label>, <p>.. y también me saca etiquetas <div>, <article> pero por ejemplo estas ultimas no quiero que salgan en el json hay alguna manera?

Comment: Es que `label` no tiene atributo "hola", si no que "hola" es un elemento hijo del tipo "Text" cuyo valor es "hola" (ver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text y https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode)

Comment: Sí, todo se puede, pero la programación no es mágica, necesito requerimientos exactos. Es decir, qué etiquetas excluir, qué datos sacar de cada etiqueta, etc... mira lo que te he dicho acerca del "value" de un label.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59602/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-t-p).